# Possible to Lookup Values in Adobe Analytics Classification Rule Builder?

Tags: adobe-analytics, web-analytics

I have tens of thousands of keys being created on a particular var.

**var Format**: *module|page name*

**var Example**: *MOD123|My Page*

I am attempting to translate the 'module' portion, and have a 'friendly name' classification output of:

*Search Box|My Page*

There are approximately 200 modules, but the 'page name' portion is multitude, and is already friendly

My initial approach was to use Classification Rules and subclassifications for the 'module' lookup. I am able to delimit the string using the pipe. However, I cannot determine how to re-concatenate the translated 'module' name

I'm faced with an option of creating 200 explicit rules to explicitly name the 'module' and leave the 'page name' as-is.

I'm suspecting there is a more elegant way to do this. Has anyone created this type of Classification Rule before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe does not currently offer any kind of lookup table feature for Classification Rule Builder (CRB). I wish they did. I've posted it on ideas.omniture.com, along with a lot of other ideas for enhancing CRB. Anyways..

The best you can do with pure CRB is create a rule for each module (one rule set with ~200 rules). Select "Regular Expression" for rule type, and for the regex, use

`^MOD123\|(.*)`

That first part `MOD123` will be a hardcoded value for each rule. Then in the **Classification Action** > **To** column, put

`Search Box|$1`

That first `Search Box` part will also be hardcoded to the "friendly" name.

[image: concatenated value rules]

So, you will wash, rinse and repeat for every Module.

The alternative would be to write your own server-side script on a cron job to receive raw values and push back classified values to Adobe, using your own lookup table (hardcoded as an array or from a db query or whatever on your own server).  You can use the Adobe SAINT API for this, or you can setup a recurring Data Warehouse export pushed to an ftp location for your script to pickup and upload to an Adobe ftp location.

**Edit:**

Another approach would be to have 2 classification columns, one only for the friendly module name, and one only for the page name. You would then have one rule to pop the page name using a regex `^[^|]+\|(.*)` and `$1` for the **To** value.

Then you would have ~200 rules (one for each module). Since you aren't trying to dynamically add anything, you can use  **Starts With** rule type, and just use the hardcoded module names (followed by a pipe), e.g. `MOD123|` and then just the friendly module name for the **To** value, e.g. "Search Box"

[image]

This will give you two classification reports with classified values like this:

[image]

I'm not sure what your actual reporting needs are, so this may or may not be what you need, but you for example go to the "Module" classification report to easily get aggregated data by module, without separate entries per page.  And you can break it down by the "Page Name" classification to see the different pages for the module.

Comment: I asked an intern to write the job using SAINT API to pull down unclassified rows on a regular basis. They would then be automatically processed and inserted via API. 

I am not fond of that approach because it is not very transparent. Further, when new modules are added (a few annually), this job will need a process to be updated. 

Granted, the CRB ruleset will need to be updated also, but given the two best options, I'm going with CRB (201 rules now) because it is a more transparent process. 

Also, I like your REGEX better than the one I wrote. Thanks.

Comment: @Kookbot eh, CRB hasn't been around all that long so I've already got a lot of experience writing my own classification scripts. You are right, it's not as transparent, but it's fairly easy to create a web interface for at least some of it to make updating it easier (e.g. a web interface to edit the lookup table).  Anyways, I had some additional thoughts, see my edit

Comment: Where is your suggestion on Idea Exchange so I may promote it?